# Autocomplete dataSource to render a ListItem Component - [material-ui]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can I render a component on autocomplete material-ui component? Like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I used MenuItem put the Avatar component inside leftIcon={}